# Having issue adding a background-image property to a row - CSS

Tags: css

I will first say that I am learning CSS right now, and I am using coffeecup RLMP as software.
I am trying to give a row a image background property but what I am doing is not working at all, if anyone could help I would very much appreciate it, thank you.

code as follows..

```
<div class="row image-here">
<div class="coffee-span-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="coffee-span-6"></div>
<div class="coffee-span-4"></div>
<div class="coffee-span-2"></div>
</div>

    css now..
body > .row.image-here {
background-image:url('');
}
```

Comment: I know the url is missing, that is not part of the issue, sorry for leaving it out.

Comment: `body > .row.image-here` this selector targets the direct child of `body`. Try with `body .row.image-here`

Comment: Tried what you suggested, but did not work Vucko..code as suggested

Comment: <div class="row image-here">
    <div class="coffee-span-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="coffee-span-6"></div>
    <div class="coffee-span-4"></div>
    <div class="coffee-span-2"></div>
  </div>

Comment: body > .row.image-here {

  background-color: transparent;
}

body .row.image-here{background-image:url('img/1.jpg'); }

Comment: You should also add some `width` and `height` for your background image - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NB76P/)

Comment: could you explain in code Vucko..i'm little new to this, sorry